# Repeating Target Values in output

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, multi-class

I have created a multiclass predictive model, however, the target values are repeating. Why one of the target value is repeating and how can it removed?

[image]

The code for this is as follows:

```
 #Defining and importing the dataset
 df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ram Prakash/Downloads/Data.xlsx", sheet_name = 
 'Multiclass')
 x = df.drop('Fault Type', axis =1)
 y = df['Fault Type']
 #y = df.iloc[0:, 10]
 #y = le.fit_transform(y)

 #Data-Preprocessing
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
 le = LabelEncoder()
 df["Fault Type"] = le.fit_transform(df["Fault Type"])

 #fvalue_selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k = 7)
 #X_kbest = fvalue_selector.fit_transform(x, y)

 #splitting the dataset
 x_train, x_Combine, y_train, y_Combine = train_test_split(x,y, train_size=0.8)


 x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_Combine, y_Combine, test_size=0.5)

 print(x_train.shape)
 print(y_val.shape)
 print(y_test.shape)

 scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
 x_train, x_test = scaler.transform(x_train), scaler.transform(x_test)

 #Training the model
 from sklearn.svm import SVC
 svclassifier = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 0.001, C = 10000)

 #fitting the dataset
 clf = OneVsOneClassifier(svclassifier).fit(x_train, y_train)
 #clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

 #Predicting Values
 Y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
 X_train_pred = clf.predict(x_train)
```

[image]

Comment: After `y = df['Fault Type']`, followed by `df["Fault Type"] = le.fit_transform(df["Fault Type"])`, are `y` and `df` what you want?

Comment: I had added those so that I target names are visible. Otherwise label encoder is converting every class to a number which is making the output unclear.

Comment: @rickg12s I have added screenshots

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed for directing you here since your question has been closed as being about programming.  Maybe it is.  I'm not sure that you are preparing your target values as you want to.  In the initial `train_test_split` you use `y`.  I don't know what `y` is, but perhaps it should be label encoded or one-hot encoded.  You may want to try that.  If there is still a statistical bias in your results, and you have questions about that, then I believe (could be wrong) that this site may be of some help.  It would also be helpful if you show exactly how your statistical measures are made.

Comment: FYI, the encoders typically have an `inverse_transform` to [_"Convert the data back to the original representation."_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.inverse_transform).

Comment: hi, @rickhg12hs yes y is label, and it is label encoded. I can try with one hot encoded as well. Also, I have tried the inverse transform but somehow it throws me an error. But I will still try it once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145726/discussion-between-akshita-and-rickhg12hs).